# free switch learning URL

Tags: unix, freeswitch

Can anyone please give me some tutorial URL for freeswitch? I am a beginner for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment the best way to start with FreeSWITCH is on its wiki page at:

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Main_Page

Have a look also at:
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Getting_Started_Guide

From that starting point you can get other resources not only on the web but also on IRC!

Have fun with FreeSWITCH!